# Setting custom foreign key column name with private field with EFCore

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the following data model:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int barId)
    {
        BarId = barId;
    }

    private int BarId;
    public Bar Bar { get; private set; }
}

public class FooTypeConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Bar)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("BarId");
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
}
```

This works great and according to my expectations, I have a `Foo` table containing `Id` and `BarId`. My private field `BarId` and my `Bar` property are also correctly materialized when reading `Foo` from the database.

The problem is that I would like to find a way to name my private field, and choose a different name for my database column. I would like to name my property `_barId` and still choose `BarId` as my column name in my database.

**Is this possible?**

---

I have tried renaming the field in my `Foo` class and specifying my (now non-conventionally-named) foreign key `_barId` in my `EntityTypeConfiguration`

```cs
builder.HasOne(x => x.Bar).WithMany().HasForeignKey("_barId");
```

But this resulted in EF still generating a `BarId` column, without using it as foreign key to the `Bar` table...

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Foos",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
        BarId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
        _barId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Foos", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Foos_Bars__barId",
            column: x => x._barId,
            principalTable: "Bars",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

[image: Foo table structure]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, EF maps database columns and FKs to entity *properties*, not fields. The properties can be real or as in your case - [shadow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties).

So the following line:

```
builder.HasOne(x => x.Bar).WithMany().HasForeignKey("BarId");
```

maps the `Bar` -> `Foo` relationship FK to a `Foo` shadow property called `BarId` and should stay as it is.

You use the `Property` method to configure the property type, backing field, column name, type and other attributes. For instance:

```
builder.Property<int>("BarId") // or int? etc.
    .HasField("_barId")
    .HasColumnName("BarId"); // or BazId or whatever you like
```

Just make sure you use one and the same property name when defining it and when specifying the FK. You can also use `Entry(entity).Property(propertyName)` to get/set the value, mark it as modified etc. as well as `EF.Property(entity, propertyName`) to access it inside LINQ to Entities queries.