# Is there a way to force _ID convention for the column name of a foreign key?

Tags: entity-framework-core, xaf

I want to use a new .net core 5 winforms, entity framework xaf application on an old database created some time ago with .net framework.

In my database the foreign keys of the security tables have names like Role_ID where as the new application expects names like RoleId

Is there a way I can cause the _ID convention without altering the Dev Express code that controls the security table structures?

For example I do not have a DBSet for PermissionPolicyMemberPermissionsObject because I never needed it with the framework app.

In the OnModelCreating I have

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<PermissionPolicyMemberPermissionsObject>()
        .ToTable("PermissionPolicyMemberPermissionsObjects")
        .HasOne<PermissionPolicyTypePermissionObject>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("TypePermissionObject_ID");
```

Yet, if I allow a new database to create, the table creates with a TypePermissionObject_ID field and a TypePermissionObjectID field.

If I try to access the old database that just has the TypePermissionObject_ID field I get errors indicating the TypePermissionObjectID is missing.

I am targetting net5.0 with

```
   <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp" Version="21.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.CodeAnalysis" Version="21.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.ConditionalAppearance" Version="21.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore" Version="21.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Validation" Version="21.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Persistent.Base" Version="21.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore" Version="21.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="5.0.13" />
```

[Update]
After studying [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622953/setting-custom-foreign-key-column-name-with-private-field-with-efcore?rq=1) I experimented with statements like

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<PermissionPolicyActionPermissionObject>()
        .ToTable("PermissionPolicyActionPermissionObjects")
        .HasOne<PermissionPolicyRoleBase>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("RoleID");
```

But I don't know how to set the Column Name.
I tried adding

modelBuilder.Entity()
.Property("RoleID").HasColumnName("Role_ID");

But that created an addition field called RoleID1
[image: table structure]

Comment: checking https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions#:~:text=The%20convention%20for%20a%20foreign,primary%20key%20property%20name%3EId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pattern works.

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<PermissionPolicyActionPermissionObject>()
        .ToTable("PermissionPolicyActionPermissionObjects")
        .HasOne<PermissionPolicyRoleBase>(x=>x.Role).WithMany(y=>y.ActionPermissions).HasForeignKey("RoleID");

    modelBuilder.Entity<PermissionPolicyActionPermissionObject>()
       .Property<int?>("RoleID").HasColumnName("Role_ID");
```